# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification (JDateChooser, JAVA)

Tags: java, date, datepicker, jcalendar

Estoy creando una replica de un programa escrito en VB.NET en JAVA a modo de practica. Estoy teniendo un problema molesto y que no he podido exactamente identificar el porque es causado... veran, estoy usando unas librerias descargadas de la siguiente fuente:

http://toedter.com/jcalendar/

En VB.NET hay un componente que se llama *DateTimePicker* que en JAVA no existe, y es el porque tuve que descargar librerias desde internet para poder obtenerlo. Estoy usando el componente *JDateChooser* que es muy similar al de VB.NET... la unica diferencia es que al elegir una fecha del mismo, el componente imprime dicha fecha en el textfield con formato de fecha corta (10/24/2016) mientras que en el otro programa original, lo imprimia en fecha larga (Lunes, 24 de octubre de 2016).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar este inconveniente, escribi una pequeña funcion en mi clase para que digamos, "convierta" o "traduzca" (como quieras llamarlo) ese formato de fecha corta a fecha larga:

```
public String getFechaLarga(String fecha) throws ParseException{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(fecha);
    c.setTime(date);
    String hoy=null;
    switch(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
        case 1: hoy="Domingo,";break;
        case 2: hoy="Lunes, ";break;
        case 3: hoy="Martes, ";break;
        case 4: hoy="Miércoles, ";break;
        case 5: hoy="Jueves, ";break;
        case 6: hoy="Viernes, ";break;
        case 7: hoy="Sábado, ";break;
    }
    hoy = hoy + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
        case 0: hoy=hoy + " de enero";break;
        case 1: hoy=hoy + " de febrero";break;
        case 2: hoy=hoy + " de marzo";break;
        case 3: hoy=hoy + " de abril";break;
        case 4: hoy=hoy + " de mayo";break;
        case 5: hoy=hoy + " de junio";break;
        case 6: hoy=hoy + " de julio";break;
        case 7: hoy=hoy + " de agosto";break;
        case 8: hoy=hoy + " de septiembre";break;
        case 9: hoy=hoy + " de octubre";break;
        case 10: hoy=hoy + " de noviembre";break;
        case 11: hoy=hoy + " de diciembre";break;
    }
    hoy = hoy + " de " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return hoy;
}
```

La funcion funciona correctamente (bueno, "casi" creo) como se puede apreciar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora vienen los problemas... y porque coloco la funcion tambien?, pues no se exactamente si es esto lo que me esta dando la excepción o no. Al inicio, me daba el error "Unparseable Date", y era porque el programa intentaba convertir a Date la cadena ya convertida del TextField de la fecha (como si tomara la fecha corta, lo convierte a fecha larga y volviese a tomar la fecha larga para convertir... pero claro, daria error porque ya estaba convertida). Lo que hice fue ponerle una condicion para regularlo (si la cadena del TextField es menor o igual a 10 caracteres, entonces procede).

```
((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).addPropertyChangeListener(
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
            try {
                if(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText().length() <= 10){                  
                    ((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).setText(admin.getFechaLarga(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText()));
                }                                       
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NuevaEntrada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Parecia funcionar todo correctamente, pero al momento yo de cambiar hacia otra fecha, me lanzo otro error mas... y esta vez se quejaba de que el JTextField de la fecha estaba "vacio". Le inserte otra condicion mas al if... (Si la cantidad de caracteres de la cadena del TextField no es igual a 0, entonces procede) Asi quedo el evento *propertyChange* a la final:

```
((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).addPropertyChangeListener(
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
            try {
                if(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText().length() <= 10 && 
                     ((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText().length() != 0){                  
                    ((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).setText(admin.getFechaLarga(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText()));
                }                                       
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NuevaEntrada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Ahora si, se supone que ya no deberia lanzar mas excepciones creo, pero lanza una ultima excepción... que es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea de codigo donde marca el error, es lo que esta dentro del if (cuando hago uso de dicha funcion que escribi, por eso estoy pensando que el error puede estar ahi):

```
 ((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).setText(admin.getFechaLarga(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).getText()));
```

Tambien puede ser que yo no este usando el evento correcto para utilizar mi funcion... quiza existan alternativas del *PropertyChangeListener* que desconosca. Vi por ahi tambien en el stackoverflow en ingles que este bug desaparece usando *SwingUtilities.invokeLater()* pero lo mas gracioso de todo, es que ya lo estoy utilizando, y no desaparece ese error...

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                NuevaEntrada nv = new NuevaEntrada("M001");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException | ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NuevaEntrada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });       
}
```

Agradeceria muchisimo su ayuda...

Comment: ¿Has probado a sobreescribir el código de la función del JDateChooser que rellena el TextField? Es la opción más común y elegante que suelo usar para customizar los controles.

Comment: No... exactamente cual función es para intentarlo @Awes0meM4n?

Comment: Ahora mismo no puedo verlo, pero la repuesta de @SJuan76 es mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `JTextFieldDateEditor` acaba usando un `SimpleDateFormat`<sup>1</sup> para formatear la fecha, y al `SimpleDateFormat` se le puede parametrizar [pasándole el String de formato que especifica el API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Por ejemplo, "Lunes, 24 de noviembre" sería algo así como "EEEE, dd 'de' MMMM".

Simplemente especifica el formato para el `SimpleDateFormat`, asegúrate que el `Locale` sea España u otro pais castellanoparlante, y olvídate de listeners y demás.

<sup>1</sup> Que suele ser, con mucho, la forma más racional de convertir texto a fechas y viceversa en Java.

Comment: He visto tu respuesta, y he utilizado lo que me dices... lo reproduce ahora en fecha larga pero ahora enfrento el siguiente problema: El JDateChooser tiene la opcion de elegir graficamente la fecha.. al momento de elegir la fecha, no esta en el año 2016, sino que esta en el diciembre de 2015....  me asegure que el Locale estuviese correcto (y de hecho, si lo esta) aqui dejo capturas para que lo veas: 
http://imgur.com/a/Mgsv3

http://imgur.com/a/YmDtt

Comment: El JDateChooser hasta me brinca para enero sin yo elegirlo.

Comment: A ver que me aclare 1) has quitado los `propertyChangeListener`s 2) Al arrancar el programa, te sale en el GUI la fecha de hoy en formato texto 3) al hacer click para el popup del calendario, automáticamente te sale "Enero" y "2015" seleccionado. ¿Es correcto, o hay algo que no sea como digo?

Comment: Asi es, quite esos eventos, me sale en el formato y al hacer click me brinca para diciembre de 2015, y si eligo otro dia, me regresa para enero de 2015 (extraño...)

Comment: Osea, el formato esta bien. Pero el popup se va por otro camino al parecer

Comment: No tanto, suena a que el popup tenga su propio `SimpleDateFormat` y haya que configurarlo también; como está mal configurado falla al parsear la fecha y pone una por defecto. Lo más normal sería que en el API del componente "padre" haya un método que permita poner el formato para ambos a la vez (en vez de sacar el componente del `JTextFieldDateEditor` y ponersélo directamente). ¿Cuál es la clase del componente?

Comment: La clase del componente que uso es JDateChooser

(com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser)

Comment: Y el formato lo pasas en el constructor (o llamando a `setDateFormatString` del `JDateChooser`), o con el "invento" que haces en tu código (`(((JTextFieldDateEditor)calendario.getDateEditor()).`) Lo dicho, parece que hay dos `SimpleDateFormat` y con el "invento" sólo cambias uno (hay que tener cuidado al romper las abstracciones)

Comment: Lo intente llamando a setDateFormatString del JDateChooser y con el "invento" (como tu le llamas jaja) y pasa lo mismo...

Comment: Pues ahí ya te queda depurar a tí, yo apuntaría a algún problema en `JTextFieldDateEditor.getDate()` convirtiendo el texto de nuevo en fecha.

Comment: Una pregunta... ¿has comprobado cuál es el funcionamiento "por defecto" (es decir, sin especificar tu el formato de fecha)? Igual lo que intentas arreglar simplemente no está implementado.

Comment: Por defecto como mencione arriba, note que el control imprime sus fechas en fecha corta. A la final lo deje asi como esta (por "default"), solo que al momento de realizar el insert, utilizaria la funcion esa que escribi para que se inserte en fecha larga a la base de datos. Mil gracias igual por tomarte el tiempo de responder! :) @SJuan76